# After an upgrade to 14.04, grub menu shows both 12.04 and 14.04

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, software-uninstall

I updated Ubuntu from 12.04 to 14.04.

The grub menu shows both Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04. I don't think the older entry should still be there. I need to remove the old one. How am I supposed to do so?

Comment: sudo apt-get install grub2.... Then update-grub2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the grub configuration file was not correctly generated.

You shouldn't need to re-install grub, but the command to do so is:

```
sudo apt-get grub-install /dev/sda
```

You definitely need to update the grub configuration:

```
sudo apt-get update-grub
```

This should remove the old entry.

If it does not, you may have old kernels still in `/boot`. There are several answers on how to remove old kernels if needed.

Comment: entering your command terminal says
 E: Invalid operation grub-install

Comment: That's odd. Did you include the /dev/sda? Also, it shouldn't be necessary, so just try the update-grub